# How to use Data binding in win forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know how to enable or disable a button depending on checking or unchecking a dynamically created check box

Comment: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html

Comment: to be continued....?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 myDynCheckBox.CheckedChanged += CBCheckedChanged;
        private void CBCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var temp = sender as CheckBox;
            if (temp != null)
            {
                if (temp.Checked)
                {
                    MyButton.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    MyButton.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private CheckBox checkBox;
        private Button button;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.Left = 12;
            checkBox.Top = 41;
            Controls.Add(checkBox);

            button = new Button();
            button.Left = 12;
            button.Top = 64;
            button.Text = "Action";
            Controls.Add(button);

            button.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", checkBox, "Checked");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would'nt do it using data-binding, but using events:

```
var mycheckBox = new CheckBox();
mycheckBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e )
  { somebutton.Enabled = mycheckBox.Checked; }
```

Comment: Your sample does not really help the OP, as it doesn't show the check box's event that actually enables/disables the button. Actually, your sample doesn't fit the question at all...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just ask for code, but this might get you on the way. These are the steps you have to follow:

- Create a CheckBox through code
- Attach an event handler to the CheckBox (also in code)
- In the event, check whether it's checker or not
- Depenging on the checked status, enable/disable the button

Also, what does this heve to do with data-binding?

Comment: i agree with you, **what does this to do with data-binding?!**